# Rails 3.1 Mountable Engines : Assets (Images) not copied to the host application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an engine that I created which have images in it (in the assets folder). When I'm testing it in the /test/dummy app, images shows, no problem.

But, when I use my mountable engine in another app, images are not copied to the assets of the host application. Everything works fine, except for this.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing a configuration that says to look for assets in the engine folder, or something like this. But I was not able to find the answer yet.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this issue.

It was as simple as do :

```
rake assets:precompile
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your engine image in YOUR_ENGINE/app/assets/images/YOUR_ENGINE/IMAGE_NAME (afaik default convention), you can access it from main application by specifying name with engine name in helper `image_path("YOUR_ENGINE/IMAGE_NAME")` without any additional configuration.

Comment: My images are indeed in that path and they are not copied to the application that use the engine. The key of the problem here is that when I use the engine, the assets are not copied to the host application. At least I believe this is the problem!